# Regex: capturing all content after numeric character and stop at specific character

Tags: regex

my message `[06/Oct/2020:17:44:24 +0200]`

my desired message

1. date for `06/Oct/2020`
2. time for `17:44:24`

my pattern `^[^:]*` for date and its returns `[06/Oct/2020`

The pattern unable to get rid of `[` character

Comment: What regex flavor?

Comment: @dawg not really sure, but I'm going to use the pattern in Logstash, Grok filter

Comment: In PCRE, you can use `\[([^:]*):([^ ]*)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDdF5x/1/) That works in *most* modern regex flavors. You need to match the `[` in order to skip it. To match it you need to escape it This is your issue.

Comment: @BTH.S3 There're tags related to logstash and grok.

Comment: @BTH.S3 Were the given answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Regex for the date:

```
(?<=\[)([^:]*)
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/PpuMJf/1).

---

Regex for the time:

```
(?<=:)\d\d:\d\d:\d\d
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/PpuMJf/2).

---

Combined regex:

```
\[([^:]*):(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)
```

Group `\1` contains the date and group `\2` contains the time.

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/PpuMJf/3).

Answer (score 0):

Using `^[^:]*` repeats a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any char except `:` and will therefore also match the leading `[`

You could use 2 capturing groups instead and make the match a bit more specific specifying a date and time related pattern.

If you want the match to be at the start of the string, you can prepend `^` to the pattern.

```
\[((?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/[A-Z][a-z]{2,}/(?:19|20)\d{2}):((?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])[^\][]*\]
```

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/[A-Z][a-z]{2,}/(?:19|20)\d{2}` Match a date like pattern
- `)` Close group 1
- `:` Match but not capture `:`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]` Match a time like pattern
- `)` Close group 2
- `[^\][]*\]` Match any char except `[` and `]` till the closing `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lwayNs/1)